# Ping causes unhandled exception

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, ping

I have a list of server IP addresses and in part of my application, before sending a request to each server, I ping it. When I test it through VS 2012, part way through, it stops and displays a page in VS, saying "Unable to connect to the remote server". I have the ping in a try-catch but it doesn't fall into the exception section; it just dies executin ping.send(). Some of the other pings time out and I catch those and display proper message. When I check the exception trace (below), it says:"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it". Is there any way to catch and handle this rather stop the program from running?

This is (partial) ping code:

```
public static string PingServer(string host)
{
    PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
    options.DontFragment = true;
    Ping p = new Ping();
    PingReply reply = null;
    string NetworkMessage = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int timeout = 120;
        Console.WriteLine(host);
        reply = p.Send(host, timeout, buffer, options);
```

This is the exception trace:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at PASSCrawlerNS.PASSCrawler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar) in c:\Users\blah\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test\test\Program.cs:line 102
       at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(Exception E)
       at System.Net.ConnectionReturnResult.SetResponses(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
       at System.Net.Connection.CompleteConnectionWrapper(Object request, Object state)
       at System.Net.PooledStream.ConnectionCallback(Object owningObject, Exception e, Socket socket, IPAddress address)
       at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectCallback()
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Object state, Boolean timedOut)
  InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
       HResult=-2147467259
       **Message=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it** 56.245.253.10:80
       Source=System
       ErrorCode=10061
       NativeErrorCode=10061
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   InnerException:
```

When I manually ping this server (56.245.253.10), it replies.

Comment: what is the exception you catch? Is this during debugging? What happens if you press F5/continue debugging?

Comment: You already have a `try` around that code, so what does the `catch` look like? Also, you can press `Ctrl+Alt+E` and check/uncheck "Thrown" under "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" to have your debugger give more/less information about exceptions in your program.

Comment: An easier question: when VS stops your program because of an exception it highlights the line. What color is it? If it's yellow you are not handling the exception. If it's green-ish it will be handled and you can hit F5 to continue running.

Comment: Why do you want to ping an IP in the range of the US Postal Service? And why is there something called PASSCrawler in the stack trace?

Comment: Actually the trace that I included contains the exception. It says: "Message=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 56.245.253.10:80". I can ping it from console and it replies. The reason I did not include the catch part is because it does not fall into it. It attempts to execute ping.send() and dies right there.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper the application is called PASSCrawler. It sends requests to a specific web page in each IP address and gets the content in response which includes some stats.

Comment: Don't understand the down vote, but oh well ...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to test if the server is active by ping method, you can try this

```
    private async Task<bool> PingHost(string ip)
    {
        bool pingable = true;
        Ping mypinger = new Ping();
        try
        {
            PingReply reply = mypinger.Send(ip);
            pingable = (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) ? true : false;
        }
        catch (PingException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return pingable;
    }
```

It runs asynchronously so doesn't block your main thread. You have to call it with await operator from another async method

Comment: It dies in mypinger.Send(ip) and does not fall into the catch section. There are other IPs that time out and that's OK. Even this is OK too, if I can find some way of catching the error, record it, and continue.

Comment: Unrelated tip: `reply.Status == IPStatus.Success` is a boolean expression, so just assign that to `pingable`.

Comment: yes @BrianRasmussen but initially when I coded that I did not have this in mind, and I am too lazy to change it later ;-)

Comment: @NoBullMan what do you mean "dies"? maybe your server or internet is slow so it is taking time to ping

Comment: I meant it does not fall into the exception section. It tries to execute ping.send() and then opens some page inside Visual studio with the error "unable to connect to remote server". However, in that VS page I can ask to display the detail exception and in there I see the trace that I included. One option I have (I think) is to bypass the ping altogether and just send a request to the server and check the status of response.

Comment: If you have some other kind of exception than pingexception, just add `Exception ex` inside catch and by `ex.Message()` you can see what exception is coming